# Change voyager model

Tags: laravel, voyager

I want to add some mutators on Voyager's User class, but I won't change anything inside vendor folder, and Voyages uses a User model inside the package. Is it possible for me to, somehow,  change this?

Comment: Never touch `vendor` because once you touch `Composer` etc. your changes won't be reflected. Also `vendor` should be always `.gitignore` so you won't be able to save your work into repo.

Comment: updated my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple enough. Modify the default Laravel User model to

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use TCG\Voyager\Models\User as VoyagerUser;

class User extends VoyagerUser {
    // add custom mutators and other code in here
}
```

Then you can update `app/config/voyager.php` as @aimme said and have it as

```
'user' => [
    'add_default_role_on_register' => true,
    'default_role'                 => 'user',
    'admin_permission'             => 'browse_admin',
    'namespace'                    => App\User::class,
],
```

This way you bring in the power of Voyager's User model to your own with no hackery involved.

Comment: I'm yet to extend Roles & Permissions, but I don't see why it wouldn't work. I extended the `VoyagerBreadController` to get some custom functionality going. You might want to give Voyager BREAD [Policies](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization#creating-policies) a look in the upcoming v1.0 release before extending Voyager's roles & permissions though, as they may help you achieve the same effect.

Comment: Interesting. Is there any news you can point me to for a release date for v1.0?

Comment: So far all we have is "very soon" from the core devs.

Comment: Please note that the `namespace` option in the `user` config of `app/config/voyager.php` is now deprecated in favour of the default user model entry in `app/config/auth.php`

Answer (score 0):

For most cases extending the vendor packages works fine.

**Update voyager configuration**

See `config/voyager.php`

change user array like this. i have changed only `namespace` here,from voyager user tp App\User.

```
'user' => [
    'add_default_role_on_register' => true,
    'default_role'                 => 'user',
    'admin_permission'             => 'browse_admin',
    'namespace'                    => App\User::class,
],
```

*but to bring additional changes you could try following way.*

**Loading whole voyager package as a local package.**

> Warning: After doing this the package would no longer be a vendor
>   package.

To do that

1 - create a packages folder on the root of the project.

2 - clone the tcg/voyager repo into the packages folder or cut paste vendor tcg folder into packages folder that you created. so you will be having your directories like this `yourproject/packages/tcg/voyager` . if you have required tcg/voyager in composer.json remove it from there.

3 - update composer.json file on the root of your project. add `TCG\\Voyager` autoload. see below sample, added the line inside psr-4.

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "TCG\\Voyager\\": "packages/tcg/voyager/src/"
        }
    },
```

4 - run composer update

sometimes you might have to do `composer dump-autoload` after bringing changes to the packages.