# Voyager-Laravel Using other table for auth

Tags: laravel, model, voyager

Everything works fine when I install Laravel with voyager, but when I try to change the users table it wont work.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41753108/change-voyager-model/45983583#45983583) step and I can only manage to login, once inside the app there is is halting process when it is loading the menu pages.

" cannot find [users] table"

```
'user' => [
'add_default_role_on_register' => true,
'default_role'                 => 'user',
'admin_permission'             => 'browse_admin',
'namespace'                    => App\User::class,
],
```

Here is my User Class

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;    

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\ResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;


class User extends extends \TCG\Voyager\Models\User {
    protected $table = 'arm.users';
}
```