# Use different User Model for Laravel Voyager

Tags: php, laravel, admin, voyager

I am developing a Laravel application, in which I use the default Laravel authentication System. I have a User model for my normal Users. I would like to use some kind of admin panel to manage the database records and the storage of the application, for which I found Voyager a suitable choice.

I decided to use a different model and database table to store admin users, but I was not able to configure Voyager for it to work.

I have tried the following documentation (https://voyager-docs.devdojo.com/customization/custom-guard), but I still get this error when tring to migrate the database, therefore my configuration must have been unsuccessful:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'email' in 'users' (SQL: alter table `users` add `avatar` varchar(255) null default 'users/default.png' after `email`, add `role_id` bigint null after `id`)

I have also tried following the answers for this issue, but these did not solve my problem neither: [Change voyager model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41753108/change-voyager-model).